# SSIS Converting between unicode and non-unicode string data types

Tags: sql-server, ssis, unicode-string

Anyone help with this one? In SSIS I have the error even thought the source ItemID and destination ItemID are both char(32). I know you can use Data Conversion in SSIS but they are the same data types.

Thanks

Error   1   Validation error. Extract Item: Extract Incident: Column "ItemID" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.     DimItem.dtsx    0   0

Comment: if you check the SSIS data type you may find that one is dt_wstr and the other is dt_str and that's causing the problem

Comment: DO you mean in the Data Conversion task? both table columns in the db are char(32). I've tried Data Conversion but the error remains weirdly enough...

Comment: We need more information about your package. What is your source and destination? How are you getting the source data (direct query, selected table in drop down). What is happening (components) between the source and destination?

Comment: A direct query, OLE DB Source to OLE DB Destination source, the query is good and tested, I only get one complaint on the ID field which is the exact same data type as source. Maybe the project needs redoing as previously I pointed it at nvarchar ID fields but since changed this to the new destination char(32) fields.

Comment: Change your query to `SELECT 1 As foo`. Your DF is then going to blow up as columns don't exist. This is desired. Then put your original query back in there. Validating metadata can be an expensive operation so sometimes the packages won't re-validate metadata if the column names are the same and the data types can be upsized to the original.

Comment: I tried turning ValidateExternalData to false but no joy, I will try confusing it now.

Comment: Still same, I will create a new package and see if that clears it...thanks

Comment: tried change back but no good, its confusing but think a new package will sort, it may be an issue in the project file itself that needs addressing.

Comment: SSIS caches column metadata at every opportunity. I would try @billinkc 's suggestion - another way to achieve the same change is to go to the OLE DB Source object's Columns page and uncheck all, click OK, then re-open, Check all, click OK.

Comment: thanks for replies guys, tried as you suggested but no luck, I then recreated the package for one of the data flows and its good to go...I can only say then it must be the meta data at the package level that's cached. I've looked at the properties of the package to see if I can reset the meta data.

Comment: Creating the package within the same data flow is ok too, so now recreating all packages in same flows and deleting old ones, is this a bug, we need a clear all cache option. Thanks

Comment: Bug? Nah. I'd classify it more as a design decision. I will note that yours is the first that instance where either changing your source query or as Mike suggested, checking and unchecking the columns didn't resolve it. If you think you can put together a minimal reproduction of the problem, I'd be happy to look into it.

Comment: Its all good now after re-creating the OLE DB connections, although I had to totally remove one package from the project altogether which again made no sense and re-created that one. If I went to the DB DM and changed the ID in question back to an nvarchar it solved it although this is not what I wanted. I will also say that on one of the other packages I tried unchecking the source fields which did remove the error although this seemed intermittent. Of course I could have scripted the DM and sorted it that way also, but got there in the end. Thanks for your help guys.